# How to handle nested list inside nested dict in Python?

Tags: python

I have following kind of data in which dict having nested dicts and that too with some nested list

> Input

```
{
  "properties": {
    "property": [
      {
        "propertyId": "508276",
        "propertyName": "State On Campus Norman",
        "budgets": {
          "budget": [
            {
              "id": "32133",
              "budgetName": "Norman 2020 Budget",
              "budgetStatusTypeId": "1",
              "isDefault": "1",
              "fiscalStartDate": "01/01/2020",
              "fiscalEndDate": "12/31/2020",
              "fiscalYear": "2020",
              "budgetTotal": "-88245.12",
              "glAccounts": {
                "glAccount": [
                  {
                    "id": 159475,
                    "accountName": "Residential Rental Revenue",
                    "accountNumber": "40000",
                    "glTotals": {
                      "glTotal": [
                        {
                          "amount": 3880956
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "budgetMonths": {
                      "budgetMonth": [
                        {
                          "month": "01/01/2020",
                          "amount": 321888
                        },
                        {
                          "month": "02/01/2020",
                          "amount": 321888
                        }]
                    }
                  },{
                    "id": 242922,
                    "accountName": "Parking Revenue",
                    "accountNumber": "40100",
                    "glTotals": {
                      "glTotal": [
                        {
                          "amount": 14760
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "budgetMonths": {
                      "budgetMonth": [
                        {
                          "month": "01/01/2020",
                          "amount": 1230
                        },
                        {
                          "month": "02/01/2020",
                          "amount": 1230
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "id": "12299",
              "budgetName": "Norman 2020 Budget",
              "budgetStatusTypeId": "1",
              "isDefault": "1",
              "fiscalStartDate": "01/01/2020",
              "fiscalEndDate": "12/31/2020",
              "fiscalYear": "2020",
              "budgetTotal": "-88245.12",
              "glAccounts": {
                "glAccount": [
                  {
                    "id": 159475,
                    "accountName": "Residential Rental Revenue",
                    "accountNumber": "40000",
                    "glTotals": {
                      "glTotal": [
                        {
                          "amount": 3880956
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "budgetMonths": {
                      "budgetMonth": [
                        {
                          "month": "01/01/2020",
                          "amount": 321888
                        },
                        {
                          "month": "02/01/2020",
                          "amount": 321888
                        }]
                    }
                  },{
                    "id": 242922,
                    "accountName": "Parking Revenue",
                    "accountNumber": "40100",
                    "glTotals": {
                      "glTotal": [
                        {
                          "amount": 14760
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "budgetMonths": {
                      "budgetMonth": [
                        {
                          "month": "01/01/2020",
                          "amount": 1230
                        },
                        {
                          "month": "02/01/2020",
                          "amount": 1230
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                  ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have to convert above data into following format. I tried with many ways but unable to succeed. Tried with flattern lib also but it is flatterning out only initial nesting. I need to find out the way which sould be dynamic.

> Output

```
{
  "properties": [
    {
      "propertyId": "508276",
      "propertyName": "State On Campus Norman"
    }
  ],
  "budgets": [
    {
      "propertyId": "508276",
      "id": "32133",
      "budgetName": "Norman 2020 Budget",
      "budgetStatusTypeId": "1",
      "isDefault": "1",
      "fiscalStartDate": "01/01/2020",
      "fiscalEndDate": "12/31/2020",
      "fiscalYear": "2020",
      "budgetTotal": "-88245.12"
    },
    {
      "propertyId": "508276",
      "id": "12299",
      "budgetName": "Norman 2020 Budget",
      "budgetStatusTypeId": "1",
      "isDefault": "1",
      "fiscalStartDate": "01/01/2020",
      "fiscalEndDate": "12/31/2020",
      "fiscalYear": "2020",
      "budgetTotal": "-88245.12"
    }
  ],
  "glAccounts": [
    {
      "id": 159475,
      "budgets_id": "32133",
      "accountName": "Residential Rental Revenue",
      "accountNumber": "40000"
    },
    {
      "id": 242922,
      "budgets_id": "32133",
      "accountName": "Parking Revenue",
      "accountNumber": "40100"
    },
    {
      "id": 212343,
      "budgets_id": "12299",
      "accountName": "Residential Rental Revenue",
      "accountNumber": "34343"
    },
    {
      "id": 455454,
      "budgets_id": "12299",
      "accountName": "Parking Revenue",
      "accountNumber": "32323"
    }
  ],
  "glTotals": [{some data list...}],
  "budgetMonths": [{some data list...}]
}
```

> Python Code that I have used to solve this

```
from flatten_dict import flatten
#'inp' is the input which I have mentioned above
flat = flatten(inp, reducer=lambda k1, k2: k2 if k1 is None else k1 + '.' + k2)
print(flat)

#Output from this code
{
    "properties.property": [
        {
            "propertyId": "508276",
            "propertyName": "State On Campus Norman",
            "budgets": {
                "budget": [.......
```

Please help to solve this using python.

Comment: Which values do you want to read?

Comment: @Sadap First code block is input and the second block is output

Comment: Where is the python code that you have tried?

Comment: @Run_Script Please have look I updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for this problem

```py
import json

inp = {}
cout = {}


def flatrn_dict(inp, name, pk_name):
    cop_in = inp.copy()
    pkn, pkv = identify_id(cop_in)
    for k, v in cop_in.items():
        if type(v) == dict:
            if pkv is not None:
                v.update({pkn: pkv})
            flatrn_dict(v, k, name)
            inp.pop(k)
        elif type(v) == list:
            for vx in v:
                if pkn is not None:
                    pkn = "{0}_id".format(pk_name)
                    vx.update({pkn: pkv})
                flatrn_dict(vx, k, name)
            arr = cout.get(name)
            if arr is None:
                cout.update({name: v})
            else:
                arr.extend(v)
                cout.update({name: arr})
            inp.pop(k)


def identify_id(ele):
    for k,v in ele.items():
        if 'id' in k.lower():
            return k, v
    return None, None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("test1.json", "r") as f:
        inp = json.load(f)
    flatrn_dict(inp, "prop", "")
    with open("test_out.json", "w") as fw:
        fw.write(json.dumps(cout))
```